# pause function in firebase mp3 player

Tags: java, android

I make the android app and I connect the android studio to Firebase
I retrieved the audio and I put the buttons of play and pause, play button is working but the pause function is not working if I press the pause button then button plays the double audio means overridden function is work and my code is:

```
play_song=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play_song);
play_song.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("gs://myapplication-3a170.appspot.com/5946_download_nokia_tune_original_ringtone.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                        mp.pause();
                    }else {
                        mp.start();
                    }

                }

                });
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `MediaPlayer` as a global variable. You are creating a new instance for each onclick. And you play again the audio every click for this reason.